# ionic swiper does not work when conditionally rendered

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic7

i am using ionic 7 and swiper component like below

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="core.loggedIn === true">
    <swiper-container #swiper (afterinit)="swiperReady()" [pagination]="true">
      <swiper-slide style="height: 600px;">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-button class="ban-half-button" (click)="goNext()">Go</ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-button class="ban-half-button" (click)="goNext()">Next</ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </swiper-slide>
 </swiper-container>
  </ng-container>
```

The code on goNext and the .ts is

```
import { Swiper } from 'swiper';

export class Tab1Page {

  @ViewChild('swiper')
  swiperRef: ElementRef | undefined;
  swiper?: Swiper;
goNext() {
    this.swiper?.slideNext();
  }

  swiperReady() {
    this.swiper = this.swiperRef?.nativeElement.swiper;
  }
}
```

This does nothing when i click on goNext() in the above code. However, if i remove the condition

```
*ngIf="core.loggedIn === true"
```

from the ng-container then it starts to work. I can sense what is happening here where the swiper does not get to initialize due to delay in when the condition becomes true. But i am not sure how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

one way of fixing this is to use the *ngIf else syntax to render the swiper container only when the condition is true, and show a loader or empty div when the condition is false. This will allow the swiper to be initialized before being rendered, ensuring it works properly.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="core.loggedIn; else showError">
  <swiper-container #swiper (afterinit)="swiperReady()" [pagination]="true">

  </swiper-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #showError>
  <ion-spinner></ion-spinner> <!-- or any other loader -->
</ng-template>
```

Comment: i will give it a try

Comment: actually it does not make sense to me. This will show loader unless loggedIn variable gets a value set to true. but it wont fix the issue of swiper initialization.

Comment: The loader will only be shown until the element is rendered and the swiper component is initialized. After that, the swiper component will work as intended.

Comment: or you can try `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook

Comment: how would you use it to trigger what?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on @ViewChild('swiper') being set by angular, you could also supply the swiper-container with the (afterinit) call: i.e.

```
<swiper-container #swiper (afterinit)="swiperReady(swiper)">
...
</swiper-container>
```

and then get the reference to the swiper on the component like:

```
public swiperReady(swiperContainer: SwiperContainer): void {
   this.swiper = swiperContainer.swiper;
}
```

The SwiperContainer can be imported from:

```
import { SwiperContainer } from 'swiper/element';
```